# Which Low-Earth Orbits Spend the Least Time With Access to Sunlight?

Tags: low-earth-orbit, solar-power, sun-synchronous

Regarding the (maybe completely absurd) possibility of powering a satellite via a ground-based laser, and perhaps (theoretically) also using that same laser to destroy any incoming projectiles or debris that might threaten the satellite, this might be most useful for a satellite that a) has little access to solar power, and/or b) is designed to be as small as possible in size (perhaps for reasons of defence?), lacking room for big solar panels or fuel tanks or batteries.. With that sci-fi thought in mind, which low-earth-orbits spend the least amount of time in the sunlight?

Comment: An as low as possible circular orbit. Coming as close as possible to the potential maximum of 50% shadow time (as on the ground). Or could it be improved by raising the apoapsis on the night side to some certain degree? Too high an apoapsis should make it worse. Does it even matter much?

Comment: Raising the apoapsis doesn't help;  Even if the apoapsis is in the middle of the umbra, the higher the apoapsis rises, the smaller the fraction of the orbit time spent in darkness becomes,

Comment: So, 50% shadow is the maximum then?

Comment: Different questions, but potentially helpful in formulating an answer to "least time in sunlight" here. [Are there any Earth orbits where the duration of eclipse increases with semi-major axis with all other parameters fixed?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/57284/12102) and [Would a lower LEO ISS orbit really have a shorter eclipse duration than a higher one?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30311/12102)

Comment: and less so [Are any Earth orbits in continual shadow of the Earth?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/55271/12102) and [Do operational Starlink satellites run their ion engines at night on batteries? And if so, do they have hi/low settings?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/55959/12102)

Comment: @notovny that feels counterintuitive but I have a hunch you can prove it with math. I'd love to see such an answer!